# Cannot write across a Linux pipe with istream and ostream pointers

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, ostream, istream

First some background:

// BEGIN BACKGROUND

I am running under CentOS 6.5 Linux on a x86_64, and compiling with c++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313.

I have a couple utility programs.  One reads a message with a constant size on its stdin, converts it to a slightly different message, and writes that to its stdout.  The other reads the slightly different message on its stdin, and sends it to a port.  I want to execute a command of the form `cat file | util1 | util2` to convert and send messages stored in the file.

I originally implemented them both using s`td::cout.write` and `std::cin.read`, and it worked fine.  However, I want to make use of a class that can do neat things with the messages and makes my utilities' code cleaner.  So, that class takes a `name` string and an `istream*` or `ostream*` and sticks them in a `std::map<std::string,std::istream>`, or a `std::map<std::string,std::ostream>` for use later.  Naturally, it's a pointer to `std::cin` or a pointer to `std::cout` that I'm putting in the maps.

Then, in `util1`, I tell it to send a message to the named stream, and it does, basically, the following (yes, I use parens that are unnecessary, because I'm paranoid):

// BEGIN SNIP

```
std::ostream *o_file = (o_file_map[name_string]);
uint32_t      sync   = fromSomewhere();
uint32_t      msgLen = sizeof(msg);

size_t        outPos = o_file->tellp();
size_t        nxtPos = o_file->write((char*)&sync,sizeof(sync)).tellp();
bool          result = ((nxtPos - outPos) == sizeof(sync));

if (result) {
    outPos = o_file->tellp();
    nxtPos = o_file->write((char*)&msgLen,sizeof(msgLen)).tellp();
    result = ((nxtPos - outPos) == sizeof(msgLen));
 } else {
    std::err << "COMPLAINT1!" << std::endl;
 }

if (result) {
    outPos = o_file->tellp();
    nxtPos = o_file->write((char*)&msg,msgLen).tellp();
    result = ((nxtPos - outPos) == msgLen);
 } else {
    std::err << "COMPLAINT2!" << std::endl;
 }

if (!result) {
    std::err << "COMPLAINT3!" << std::endl;
 }

o_file->flush();
```

// END SNIP

In `util2`, I tell it to look for a message, and it does, essentially, this:

// BEGIN SNIP

```
std::istream *i_file  = (i_file_map[name_string]);
uint32_t      tstSync = 0;
uint32_t      msgSize = 0; // Yeah, I called it msgLen before.
bool          ok      = true;
bool          do_flip = false;
size_t        readLen = 0;

if (*i_file) {
    readLen = i_file->read((char*)&tstSync, sizeof(tstSync)).gcount();
    ok = (readLen / sizeof(tstSync) > 0);
 }

if (ok && (*i_file)) {
    readLen = i_file->read((char*)&msgSize, sizeof(msgSize)).gcount();
    ok = (readLen / sizeof(msgSize) > 0);
 }

if (ok) {
    if (!isSync(tstSync)) {
        if (isFlippedSync(tstSync)) {
            do_flip = true;
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
    }

    if (isSync(msgSize)) {
        std::cerr << "This is not supposed to be a sync word" << std::endl;
        ok = false;
    }

    if (do_flip) {
        msgSize = flip(msgSize);
    }
 }

if (ok) {
    Size_msg_buf_to(msgSize); // enlarges object's buffer iff it's too small.
    // it would throw an exception if it failed.
 }

if (ok && (*i_file)) {
    readLen = i_file->read(msg_buf, msgSize).gcount();
    ok = (readLen / msgSize > 0);
 }
```

// END SNIP

OK, so that's what I'm doing.

// END BACKGROUND

Here's the mystery:

When I run the first utility to a file `cat file | util1 > msgFile` and then feed that file to the second utility `cat msgFile | util2` it works just fine.  So, I know the writes are all happening in the proper order.  But, if I pipe the data between the utilities directly `cat file | util1 | util2` it doesn't work!  I appear to be reading the sync word over and over again instead of reading messages (my "This is not supposed to be a sync word" message spews out, apparently for every read).  The first utility runs without complaints (the "COMPLAINT" messages don't come out).

Now, my understanding of Linux pipes is that, first, they're supposed to deliver the data in order.  Second, if the buffer is empty, read operations at the terminus block.  Third, if the buffer is full, write operations at the source block.  Fourth, they use a 64K buffer, which is *way* more than I need for my little messages, so it's not like they wouldn't fit.  So, in short, I shouldn't be seeing buffer overflows, and I don't know what else would be different between writing to file and writing to a pipe.

So, it works if I use std::cout.write and std::cin.read with all this code placed directly in my utility.  And it works with `(istream*)&std::cin` and `(ostream*)&std::cout` from my maps if I pipe the `util1` output to a file and pipe the file to the input of `util2`, but it doesn't work with `(istream*)&std::cin` and `(ostream*)&std::cout` from my maps if I pipe the `util1` output to the input of `util2`.

This is driving me nuts!  Can anybody tell me what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Format your code properly please. Also this isn't a phpbb forum, SO uses markdown for fomatting not phpbb tags.

Comment: I fixed your formatting, why did you undo it? You made it even worse than the original!

Comment: @Barmar Rolled back to your version.

Comment: @Barmar by accident, sorry.  Hard to edit on phone, hard to login on work computer.

Comment: That code is still barely readable. To the poster: You might have to handle partially read messages. I wouldn't use streams for that, because they are made for text formatting and parsing. Instead, use a streambuffer, which is a lower-level part of a stream. Still, you need to disable line ending conversions and possible codecvt facts.

Comment: I'm a little concerned about using `tellp` on a pipe stream.

Comment: Ooo.  Good call.  That could be different between a file and a pipe.  I'll check into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victory!  Thanks Barmar!

There are two problems with the code above; the first one is embarrassing.

1. The writer complaints go into a logfile, and I totally looked in the wrong logfile.  The correct logfile was full of complaints.
2. I can't use tellp on a pipe stream.

So, it works if I write as follows:

```
std::ostream *o_file = (o_file_map[name_string]);
uint32_t      sync   = fromSomewhere();
uint32_t      msgLen = sizeof(msg);

size_t        outPos = o_file->tellp();
bool          result = (o_file->write((char*)&sync,sizeof(sync))).good();

if (result) {
    result = (o_file->write((char*)&msgLen,sizeof(msgLen))).good();
} else {
    std::err << "COMPLAINT1!" << std::endl;
}

if (result) {
    result = (o_file->write((char*)&msg,msgLen)).good();
} else {
    std::err << "COMPLAINT2!" << std::endl;
}

if (!result) {
    std::err << "COMPLAINT3!" << std::endl;
}

o_file->flush();
```

I'd still like to know how many bytes I wrote with each call, but I suppose it's either everything or nothing.  I'm not 100% confident that a bad write will have written nothing, though.

Comment: I'd like to give credit to Barmar for this one, but he wrote a comment rather than an answer.  So, I'll check off the question with this.